# DataTables sorts strings instead of numeric

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using [jquery.datatables](http://datatables.net/) to show numbers in datatables columns. Numbers are formatted to have spaces in between thousands unit (like `123 456 789`). Unfortunately, this number formatting provoques a *string* sorting instead of a *number* sorting (see the screenshot at the end of this question).

I have identified that:

- `function _fnSort(oSettings, bApplyClasses) {` is the core function for sorting.
- In this function, the *dynamic function sorting* approach is used (the one executed if `if (!window.runtime) {` is true)
- The **string sorting functions** used are the two following functions.

  ```
  /*
  * text sorting
  */
  "string-asc": function(a, b) {
      var x = a.toLowerCase();
      var y = b.toLowerCase();
      return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
  },

  "string-desc": function(a, b) {
      var x = a.toLowerCase();
      var y = b.toLowerCase();
      return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
  },
  ```

My knowledge in javascript is pretty poor, what would be the best approach here?

1. Tweak the string sorting function to detect the *number thousands formatted* case, and do the comparison (I guess this would be pretty slow on large data set).
2. Provide a numerical sorting function dedicated for *number thousands formatted*? In that case

   - how would you code that?
   - how could I indicate to the core sorting function, to use this special numerical sorting function?

Here is what the sorting look like by now:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To sort this kind of values, you can use this sort function :

```
var sortFunction=function(a, b)​{
    var ia = parseInt(a.split(' ').join(''), 10);
    var ib = parseInt(b.split(' ').join(''), 10);
    return ia-ib;
};
```

Test :

```
var data = ['3 333', '100 333', '22 000', '1 333'];
console.log(data.sort(sortFunction));
```

With a reasonable number of values, this will be fast enough. You shouldn't try to enrich the data if you don't detect performance problems.

**EDIT :**

In fact, [the documentation](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) proposes an appropriate (similar) sorting function :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "formatted_numbers-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
    },

    "formatted_numbers-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "formatted_numbers-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```

After having added this extension, you just have to set the `sType` of your column.

Comment: Awesome! But then how could I force _fnSort() to use this sorting function for the concerned column?

Comment: Author of DataTables here - nice answer - up voted. I'd suggest marking as correct/accepted :-). Only typo is the sType as an uppercase 'T': http://datatables.net/ref#sType . Also worth pointing out that there are lots of other sorting plug-ins (some with type detection counterparts) - http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the typo, now fixed.

Comment: Great! I'll try this this afternoon and will let you know :)

Comment: Ok, I stumble on another issue: how to "set the sType of my column". I can see the javascript code in the section of the doc "How to use DataTables plug-in sorting functions functions (type based)". How can I use this javascript code if I have plenty of dataTable defined in my html? Ideally I'd imagine something like <thead><th sType="numeric2">XX</th></thead>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of search, I found an alternative solutions. The solution proposed by *dystroy* and *Allan Jardine* is certainly cleaner. But it implies touching the HTML and in [my case](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx), touching the HTML provoked tricky message box like this one below.

[image]

So my solution is to just touch the javascript string sorting algo, to switch between the numeric and textual cases. I wish it could be cleaner by using something like `isDigit(sa.charAt[0])` but it just don't work despite all my attempts. At least this solution works and doesn't imply any noticeable performance cost:

```
    /*
    * text + integer sorting
    */
    "string-asc": function(a, b) {
       var sa = a.toString();
       if(sa.length > 0) {
          // Don't know why, isDigit(sa.charAt[0]) doesn't work??
          var ca = sa.substring(0,1);
          if(ca === "0" || ca === "1" || ca === "2" || ca === "3" || ca === "4" || ca === "5" || ca === "6" || ca === "7" || ca === "8" || ca === "9") {
             var x1 = parseInt(a.split(' ').join(''), 10);
             var y1 = parseInt(b.split(' ').join(''), 10);
             return x1 - y1;
          }
       }
       var x = a.toLowerCase();
       var y = b.toLowerCase();
       return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "string-desc": function(a, b) {
        var sa = a.toString();
        if(sa.length > 0) {
           var ca = sa.substring(0,1);
           if(ca === "0" || ca === "1" || ca === "2" || ca === "3" || ca === "4" || ca === "5" || ca === "6" || ca === "7" || ca === "8" || ca === "9") {
              var x1 = parseInt(a.split(' ').join(''), 10);
              var y1 = parseInt(b.split(' ').join(''), 10);
              return y1 - x1;
           }
        }
        var x = a.toLowerCase();
        var y = b.toLowerCase();
        return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that is reading this and want the complete answer for space between numbers :

```
  jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
      "formatted_numbers-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a===" ") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
      },

      "formatted_numbers-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
      },

      "formatted_numbers-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
      }
  } );

    $('.myTable').DataTable({
      "columnDefs": [
        { "type": "formatted_numbers", "targets": 4 }
      ],
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set decimal point when building the DataTable like this:

```
var main_table = $('#main_list').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/your/data",
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "Col1" },
        { data: "Col2" },
        { data: "Col3" },
        { data: "Col4" }
    ],
    language: {
        /* -----> */ "decimal": ",", // <---------
        "emptyTable": "Keine Daten in der Tabelle verfügbar",
        "info": "Anzeigen von _START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
        "infoEmpty": "Anzeigen von 0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtriert von_MAX_ Gesamteinträge)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        /* -----> */ "thousands": ".", // <---------
        "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",
        "loadingRecords": "Laden...",
        "processing": "Verarbeitung...",
        "search": "Suche:",
        "zeroRecords": "Keine passenden Datensätze gefunden",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Erste",
            "last": "Letzte",
            "next": "Nächste",
            "previous": "Vorherige"
        },
        "aria": {
            "sortAscending": ": aufsteigend sortieren",
            "sortDescending": ": absteigend sortieren"
        }
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {//set german formatting

            render: function (data, type, row) {
                return formatDE(data,2);
            },
            targets: [2, 4, 5]
        },
        {

            render: function (data, type, row) {
                return formatDE(data,0);
            },
            targets: [3]
        }
    ],
    pageLength: 50});
```

If you dig in more into `jquery.dataTables.js` you will find that they have a function which determines the type of every column value and catches the format